# a comment in case of field empty php?

Tags: php, html

I have 3 PHP files , the first one contain fields to compile which mean in html a form. the second ,  the code that took the fields from the first file and register them inside a folder `.txt` with a title=the date and time , the third file confirm the registration: i did the 3 files they work : but i would like to reload the fields page, in case where I click on the button and one or more of the fields is empty, with a comment near the field empty :

the first file `form.php` is:

I put the code only with one field to don't disturb more :`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  }
    <form action="POST.PHP" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="name"  value="name">

        <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

the second file POST.php contain :

```
<?php
$nameErr= "";
$name = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Missing";
    } else {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $filename="file/". date("Y-m-d_H_m_s")  .  "_" . uniqid() . ".txt" ;
        $fp = fopen( $filename, "w" );
        fwrite($fp, $name);
        fclose($fp);
        include 'registred.php';
    }
}
?>
```

and the third file registred.php contain :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>completed registration</h2>
   <h3>wish to see you soon !!</h3>
    <ul>
    <li >name:<?=htmlspecialchars($name)?></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to do that but its good enough to give you a idea about how u r gonna manage this.

```
    <?php session_start();?>
    <form action="post.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="txtName">
          <?php
               if(isset($_SESSION['mising_data'])){
                    echo $_SESSION['mising_data'];
               }
          ?>
          <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit">
        </form>
```

now in post.php file

```
          <?php
              session_start();
              if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
                 if (empty($_POST['txtName'])) {
                     $_SESSION['mising_data'] = 'missing Data';
                     header('Location: form.php');
                 }
              }
          ?>
```

to handle this professionally u should use jquery ajax() method